# Thread was being aborted at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Params()

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

In our application, We have one request handler(.ashx) which reads request params and provides the response.

But some time we get "Thread was being aborted." at below statement in code.

```
context.Request.Params["action"]
```

Stack trace :

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInParamsCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetParams()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Params()
```

Can anyone assist us on this?

We have started seeing error after adding  in web.config. Is there any relevance with this setting?

```
<!-- 10MB in kilobytes, default is 4096 or 4MB-->
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
```

This error is not frequently generated may be 5 time on 10,000 call.

Comment: Are the requests longer than 10240? If you test with requests longer than 10240 do you get the same error message?

Comment: Hi Chris,
That was not the case.
I have already tried to upload an image of size 14.9 mb.